# Using Guava CacheBulilder() to build extended AbstractCache() object

Tags: inheritance, guava

I would like to extend Guava's [AbstractCache()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/AbstractCache.html) class (an implementation of the Cache interface) to override some of the built-in functions of the Cache interface.

However, as [CacheBuilder()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) is typically used to build a cache and returns a Cache type object, I'm not sure how to go about building a cache of my extended class type, since using CacheBuilder would return a type of the parent class. So it would be downcasting.

```
import com.google.common.cache.{Cache, AbstractCache, CacheBuilder}

// this works normally
Cache validCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder.build()

// extending AbstractCache, an abstract class implementation of Cache interface
class MyCache extends AbstractCache {...}

// this doesn't work since the return value of calling build()
// is Cache, parent type of MyCache
MyCache invalidCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder.build()
```

I think I'm missing something, since the documentation of the AbstractCache() class says specifically that it is an implementation of the Cache interface to make it easier for programmers to extend their own class, presumably to build a cache from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use `CacheBuilder` but rather instantiate your `MyCache` directly yourself. `CacheBuilder` is merely a constructor for `Cache` instances (that assumes you'd implement any fancy stuff all by yourself).

As a side note, why are you extending `AbstractCache` at all? Maybe [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) would be sufficient?